# How to properly do a global onBackPressed() override?

Tags: android

I want to override onBackPressed() and I have this code in all my activities

```
int backpress=0;
public void onBackPressed(){
    backpress = (backpress + 1);
    if (backpress>1) {
        this.finish();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.finish, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

But I only want to override the function one time if it's possible. Whats the proper way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Base activity and define this method there. Like

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    private int backpress = 0;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        backpress = (backpress + 1);
        if (backpress > 1) {
            this.finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.finish,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And extend this BaseActivity instead of Activity ino your activity. Like

```
// Just override BaseActivity instead of Activity class.
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity {
    // Do you task
}
```